# Why cannot scroll ScrollView Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I want to scroll `ScrollView` programmatically but i can't.

None of `ScrollView` methods "`scrollTo`, `arrowScroll`, `pageScroll` and `fullScroll`" doesn't work!

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollbar_textchat);
Button sendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
```

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--main-->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollbar_textchat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
            android:fillViewport="true">
                <!--messages list-->
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_textchat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
        </ScrollView>
        <!--/main-->

        <!--line-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#FFEEEEEE"/>

        <!--already Typing message...-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.salamatyar.components.TypingAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/typing_textchat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_typing_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="typing" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--/already Typing message...-->

        <!--line-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#FFEEEEEE"/>

        <!--type-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="send"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--/type-->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
 final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollbar_textchat);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
             scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
        } 
});
```

use ListView: to scroll to bottom poistion

```
  listView.post(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
    listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);
  }});
```

Comment: You are adding `scrollview` to `Listview` Only. ..so try scrolling the listview instead..check the edit

Comment: Also another query: did ur manual scroll works on listview items?

Comment: thank you very much, i scrolled `Listview` and did worked.

Answer (score 1):

xml layout:

remove

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar_textchat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
        android:fillViewport="true">
          -------------------------------
    </ScrollView>
```

and use  android:layout_weight="1"

```
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_textchat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should run the code inside the scrollView.post like this:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i tested this before and didn't work!

Comment: that is strange! this is always works for me, any way, did you tried `scrollView.postDelayed` instead of `scrollView.post`